# Double Recursive Call with a System Out Print in between these calls Ap computer science

Tags: java, recursion

I thought I understood recursion until I got to this method. I am absolutely dumbfounded by the timing of this thing, and thus am requesting help from you guys.

```
public static void mystery5(String sWord)
{
    int nL = sWord.length();
    if(nL >= 3)
    {
         mystery5(sWord.substring(0, nL/3));
         System.out.println(sWord.substring(nL/3, 2*nL/3));
         mystery5(sWord.substring(2*nL/3));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    mystery5("la-la-la");       
}
```

The output is :

```
-la 
l
```

Comment: Yessir this is the java my good sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's note that if the recursive function is called with a string of length 2 or less, it does strictly nothing.

Second, let's replace some variables by their values to better understand this :

The string "la-la-la" has length 8.

8/3 == 2 (in integer arithmetic)

And

2*8/3 == 16/3 == 5

So, in the **first call** ("1"), we have this :

```
     mystery5(sWord.substring(0, 2));
     System.out.println(sWord.substring(2, 5));
     mystery5(sWord.substring(5));
```

Which means :

```
     mystery5("la");            // let's name this "2A", it will not print anything
     System.out.println("-la"); // prints "-la"
     mystery5("-la");           // let's name this "2B", this will do something
```

Can you do by yourself for this second call the same development I just did?

---

The stack will look like this, if you go step by step, with the names of the mystery5 calls as written above :

```
START
main
main - "1"
main - "1" - "2A"
main - "1"     -----> print "-la"
main - "1" - "2B"
main - "1" - "2B" - "3A"
main - "1" - "2B"    ----> print "l"
main - "1" - "2B" - "3B"
main - "1" - "2B"
main - "1"
main
END
```

Comment: I don't understand how the stack works when you finish the first method and get to the second method. How would the second method work visually/step-by-step?

Comment: @RushilVellala which are you calling "first" and "second" method ? Are you talking about `main` and `mystery5` ? 
Or different *calls* of `mystery5` ?

Comment: Also, just for information, int total `mystery5` is called 5 times. First call from main, and twice from this first call. The first of the latter calls do nothing, but the second one will do something (since the length of "-la" is 3). And it will itself call `mystery5` two other times.

Comment: Can you use a debugger to go step by step through the code ? In the meantime, I'll try to clarify what happens on the stack.

Comment: @RushilVellala I edited my question to added how the stack behaves.